# Python Script not connected to elements on folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I'm trying to use this github code so i can learn things from it [Link To Github Code](https://github.com/alanchavez88/theHarvester) , the issue i'm having is in my pycharm **(same thing when i run with cmd without pycharm)** is when i try to run script, it doesn't work because the script cannot import elements in the same folder.

Here an image that explains everything

[image]

Comment: Is `dns` from a package you installed? Otherwise, you may need to use relative imports. You can read more about [imports](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) and [absolute vs relative](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/). A quick fix will be, in `dnssearch.py` to have `from . import dns`. But, if `dns` is supplied by an installed package, make sure you installed it in your venv.

Comment: @edd dns is another folder included on discovery's folder ( theHarvester-master -> discovery -> DNS )

Answer (score 0):

```
# Willnot work because you ask python to import all files from a folder
# but python what to import all codes from a file
# Think like that: from FILE import ALL_CODS
from discovery.file_1 import *
from discovery.folder.file_2 import *
```